# CKEditor - how to disable pastefromword

Tags: ckeditor

This one is killing me. I have not been able to find the solution for one hour. The question is - how do I completely disable pastefromword in CKEditor? I want the pasted text to be plain - not edited at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

In ckeditor/config.js, use:

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

For more details: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html

Answer (score 3):

choose the file CKEditor\CKEditor.js

look for keyword "**i.toolbar_Full**"

manipulate the following chunk of code to add, disable or change location of icons

```
i.toolbar_Full=[['Source','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'],['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print','SpellChecker','Scayt'],['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],['Form','Checkbox','Radio','TextField','Textarea','Select','Button','ImageButton','HiddenField'],'/',['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote','CreateDiv'],['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],['BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],['Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe'],'/',['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],['TextColor','BGColor'],['Maximize','ShowBlocks','-','About']];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try with this code (config.js)**

```
config.removePlugins = 'PasteFromWord';
```

it may be helpful to You...

Answer (score 1):

there ya go...

```
config.removeButtons = 'PasteFromWord';
```

add that line of code to your `config.js` file at the bottom..

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines in your config.js file :

```
config.pasteFromWord=true;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
config.pasteFromWordNumberedHeadingToList =true;
```